# How to rotate an image back and forth with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a website and on the website I want the faces to rotate to  certain point and then rotate back in the opposite direction until a certain point, I would like it if they could keep doing this forever but I can only get it to do a full rotation forever does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>BSDC</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>    
        var looper;
        var degrees = 0;
        function rotateAnimation(el,speed){
            var elem = document.getElementById(el);
            if(navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome")){
                elem.style.WebkitTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
            } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Firefox")){
                elem.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
            } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")){
                elem.style.msTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
            } else if(navigator.userAgent.match("Opera")){
                elem.style.OTransform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
            } else {
                elem.style.transform = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
            }
            looper = setTimeout('rotateAnimation(\''+el+'\','+speed+')',speed);
            degrees++;
            if(degrees > 359){
                degrees = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "rotate("+degrees+"deg)";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="Dave" src="Images/Dave.png"/>
    <script>rotateAnimation("Dave",30);</script>
    <img id="Andy" src="Images/Andy.png" />
    <script>rotateAnimation("Andy",30);</script>
    <img id="Dan" src="Images/Dan.png" />
    <script>rotateAnimation("Dan",30);</script>
    <img id="Nico" src="Images/Nico.png" />
    <script>rotateAnimation("Nico",30);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("Images/BSDC.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#Dave {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
#Andy {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 35%;
    position: absolute;
}
#Dan {
    margin-left: 85%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    position: absolute;
}
#Nico {
    margin-left: 85%;
    margin-top: 35%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/1793tvaq/1/

Comment: Are you familiar with css animations at all? You don't need any js for this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o9zd5tvp/23/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this all with CSS animation. Check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ks6sfsm0/)

the browser prefixes are annoying... and if anybody knows if this can be simplified please comment. But this is the concept, you set an animation on your element:

```
#box {
  -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 5s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

and then you define your animation, you can do any property changes and make as many steps in it as possible, i just used basic values (0, 25, 50 100)

```
@keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  25% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(-45deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

You can read up on this stuff on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)